# Regex Problems, extracting data to groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How I love regex!

I have a string which will be a mangled form of XML, like:

```
<Category>DIR</Category><Location>DL123A</Location><Reason>Because</Reason><Qty>42</Qty><Description>Some Desc</Description><IPAddress>127.0.0.1</IPAddress>
```

Everything will all be on one line, however the 'headers' will often be different.

So what I need to do is extract all information from the string above, putting it into a Dictionary/Hashtable

--

```
string myString = @"<Category>DIR</Category><Location>DL123A</Location><Reason>Because</Reason><Qty>42</Qty><Description>Some Desc</Description><IPAddress>127.0.0.1</IPAddress>";

//this will extract the name of the label in the header
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<header><[A-Za-z]+>?)");

//Create a collection of matches
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(myString);

foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    headers.Add(m.Groups["header"].Value);
}


//this will try and get the values.
r = new Regex(@"(?'val'>[A-Za-z0-9\s]*</?)");

mc = r.Matches(myString);

foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    string match = m.Groups["val"].Value;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match) || match == "><" || match == "> <")
        continue;
    else
        values.Add(match);
}
```

--
I hacked that together from previous work with regexes to the closest I could.
But it doesnt really work the way I want it.

the 'header' also pulls the angle brackets in.

The 'value' pulls in a lot of empties (hence the dodgy if statement in the loop). It also doesnt work on strings with periods, commas, spaces, etc.

It would also be much better if I could combine the two statements so I dont have to loop through the regex twice.

Can anyone give me some info where I can improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it looks like XML, why not use the XML parser functionalities of .net? All you need to do is to add a root element around it:

```
string myString = @"<Category>DIR</Category><Location>DL123A</Location><Reason>Because</Reason><Qty>42</Qty><Description>Some Desc</Description><IPAddress>127.0.0.1</IPAddress>";

var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var xml = XDocument.Parse("<root>" + myString + "</root>");
foreach(var e in xml.Root.Elements()) {
    values.Add(e.Name.ToString(), e.Value);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. You should almost always favor XML parsers over regex when you can. That's what they're for.

Comment: Thanks for that. I never even thought of using an XML parser, because it was badly formed to begin with. It's saved me a lot of regex headaches.

Answer (score 1):

This should strip the angle brackets:

```
 Regex r = new Regex(@"<(?<header>[A-Za-z]+)>");
```

and this should get rid of empty spaces:

```
r = new Regex(@">\s*(?'val'[A-Za-z0-9\s]*)\s*</");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will match the headers without <>:

```
(?<=<)(?<header>[A-Za-z]+)(?=>)
```

This will get all values (i'm not sure about what can be accepted as a value) :

```
(?<=>)(?'val'[^<]*)(?=</)
```

However this is all xml so You can :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>",myString));
var pairs = doc.Root.Descendants().Select(node => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(node.Name.LocalName, node.Value));
```